# É possível criar um gráfico chord diagram utilizando a biblioteca d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

É possível criar um gráfico em *chord* utilziando a biblioteca `d3`?

Segue estrutura de dados do gráfico em formato *`JSON`*:

```
    {"links": [
    {
        "id": "11",
        "color": "#d96500\r\n\r\n",
        "source": "Norte ",
        "target": "Norte",
        "id2": "11",
        "value": "110042",
        "total": "112827",
        "percentagem": "97.53"
    },
    {
        "id": "11",
        "color": "#bdb66c\r\n",
        "source": "Norte ",
        "target": "Algarve",
        "id2": "15",
        "value": "148",
        "total": "112827",
        "percentagem": "0.13"
    },
    {
        "id": "11",
        "color": "#bdaf57\r\n",
        "source": "Norte ",
        "target": "Centro",
        "id2": "16",
        "value": "1533",
        "total": "112827",
        "percentagem": "1.36"
    },
    {
        "id": "11",
        "color": "#fffbc4\r\n",
        "source": "Norte ",
        "target": "Lisboa",
        "id2": "17",
        "value": "810",
        "total": "112827",
        "percentagem": "0.72"
    },
    {
        "id": "11",
        "color": "#f5b367",
        "source": "Norte ",
        "target": "Alentejo",
        "id2": "18",
        "value": "180",
        "total": "112827",
        "percentagem": "0.16"
    },
    {
        "id": "11",
        "color": "#f5b367\r\n",
        "source": "Norte ",
        "target": "Região Autónoma dos Açores",
        "id2": "20",
        "value": "66",
        "total": "112827",
        "percentagem": "0.06"
    },
    {
        "id": "11",
        "color": "#decf00\r\n",
        "source": "Norte ",
        "target": "Região Autónoma da Madeira",
        "id2": "30",
        "value": "48",
        "total": "112827",
        "percentagem": "0.04"
    },
    {
        "id": "15",
        "color": "#d96500\r\n\r\n",
        "source": "Algarve ",
        "target": "Norte",
        "id2": "11",
        "value": "37",
        "total": "11633",
        "percentagem": "0.32"
    },
    {
        "id": "15",
        "color": "#bdb66c\r\n",
        "source": "Algarve ",
        "target": "Algarve",
        "id2": "15",
        "value": "11202",
        "total": "11633",
        "percentagem": "96.30"
    },
    {
        "id": "15",
        "color": "#bdaf57\r\n",
        "source": "Algarve ",
        "target": "Centro",
        "id2": "16",
        "value": "53",
        "total": "11633",
        "percentagem": "0.46"
    },
    {
        "id": "15",
        "color": "#fffbc4\r\n",
        "source": "Algarve ",
        "target": "Lisboa",
        "id2": "17",
        "value": "240",
        "total": "11633",
        "percentagem": "2.06"
    },
    {
        "id": "15",
        "color": "#f5b367",
        "source": "Algarve ",
        "target": "Alentejo",
        "id2": "18",
        "value": "95",
        "total": "11633",
        "percentagem": "0.82"
    },
    {
        "id": "15",
        "color": "#f5b367\r\n",
        "source": "Algarve ",
        "target": "Região Autónoma dos Açores",
        "id2": "20",
        "value": "4",
        "total": "11633",
        "percentagem": "0.03"
    },
    {
        "id": "15",
        "color": "#decf00\r\n",
        "source": "Algarve ",
        "target": "Região Autónoma da Madeira",
        "id2": "30",
        "value": "2",
        "total": "11633",
        "percentagem": "0.02"
    },
    {
        "id": "16",
        "color": "#d96500\r\n\r\n",
        "source": "Centro ",
        "target": "Norte",
        "id2": "11",
        "value": "1211",
        "total": "68002",
        "percentagem": "1.78"
    },
    {
        "id": "16",
        "color": "#bdb66c\r\n",
        "source": "Centro ",
        "target": "Algarve",
        "id2": "15",
        "value": "143",
        "total": "68002",
        "percentagem": "0.21"
    },
    {
        "id": "16",
        "color": "#bdaf57\r\n",
        "source": "Centro ",
        "target": "Centro",
        "id2": "16",
        "value": "63709",
        "total": "68002",
        "percentagem": "93.69"
    },
    {
        "id": "16",
        "color": "#fffbc4\r\n",
        "source": "Centro ",
        "target": "Lisboa",
        "id2": "17",
        "value": "2249",
        "total": "68002",
        "percentagem": "3.31"
    },
    {
        "id": "16",
        "color": "#f5b367",
        "source": "Centro ",
        "target": "Alentejo",
        "id2": "18",
        "value": "617",
        "total": "68002",
        "percentagem": "0.91"
    },
    {
        "id": "16",
        "color": "#f5b367\r\n",
        "source": "Centro ",
        "target": "Região Autónoma dos Açores",
        "id2": "20",
        "value": "39",
        "total": "68002",
        "percentagem": "0.06"
    },
    {
        "id": "16",
        "color": "#decf00\r\n",
        "source": "Centro ",
        "target": "Região Autónoma da Madeira",
        "id2": "30",
        "value": "34",
        "total": "68002",
        "percentagem": "0.05"
    },
    {
        "id": "17",
        "color": "#d96500\r\n\r\n",
        "source": "Lisboa ",
        "target": "Norte",
        "id2": "11",
        "value": "279",
        "total": "83584",
        "percentagem": "0.33"
    },
    {
        "id": "17",
        "color": "#bdb66c\r\n",
        "source": "Lisboa ",
        "target": "Algarve",
        "id2": "15",
        "value": "272",
        "total": "83584",
        "percentagem": "0.33"
    },
    {
        "id": "17",
        "color": "#bdaf57\r\n",
        "source": "Lisboa ",
        "target": "Centro",
        "id2": "16",
        "value": "960",
        "total": "83584",
        "percentagem": "1.15"
    },
    {
        "id": "17",
        "color": "#fffbc4\r\n",
        "source": "Lisboa ",
        "target": "Lisboa",
        "id2": "17",
        "value": "81247",
        "total": "83584",
        "percentagem": "97.20"
    },
    {
        "id": "17",
        "color": "#f5b367",
        "source": "Lisboa ",
        "target": "Alentejo",
        "id2": "18",
        "value": "726",
        "total": "83584",
        "percentagem": "0.87"
    },
    {
        "id": "17",
        "color": "#f5b367\r\n",
        "source": "Lisboa ",
        "target": "Região Autónoma dos Açores",
        "id2": "20",
        "value": "46",
        "total": "83584",
        "percentagem": "0.06"
    },
    {
        "id": "17",
        "color": "#decf00\r\n",
        "source": "Lisboa ",
        "target": "Região Autónoma da Madeira",
        "id2": "30",
        "value": "54",
        "total": "83584",
        "percentagem": "0.06"
    },
    {
        "id": "18",
        "color": "#d96500\r\n\r\n",
        "source": "Alentejo ",
        "target": "Norte",
        "id2": "11",
        "value": "46",
        "total": "21572",
        "percentagem": "0.21"
    },
    {
        "id": "18",
        "color": "#bdb66c\r\n",
        "source": "Alentejo ",
        "target": "Algarve",
        "id2": "15",
        "value": "195",
        "total": "21572",
        "percentagem": "0.90"
    },
    {
        "id": "18",
        "color": "#bdaf57\r\n",
        "source": "Alentejo ",
        "target": "Centro",
        "id2": "16",
        "value": "508",
        "total": "21572",
        "percentagem": "2.35"
    },
    {
        "id": "18",
        "color": "#fffbc4\r\n",
        "source": "Alentejo ",
        "target": "Lisboa",
        "id2": "17",
        "value": "1265",
        "total": "21572",
        "percentagem": "5.86"
    },
    {
        "id": "18",
        "color": "#f5b367",
        "source": "Alentejo ",
        "target": "Alentejo",
        "id2": "18",
        "value": "19542",
        "total": "21572",
        "percentagem": "90.59"
    },
    {
        "id": "18",
        "color": "#f5b367\r\n",
        "source": "Alentejo ",
        "target": "Região Autónoma dos Açores",
        "id2": "20",
        "value": "8",
        "total": "21572",
        "percentagem": "0.04"
    },
    {
        "id": "18",
        "color": "#decf00\r\n",
        "source": "Alentejo ",
        "target": "Região Autónoma da Madeira",
        "id2": "30",
        "value": "8",
        "total": "21572",
        "percentagem": "0.04"
    },
    {
        "id": "20",
        "color": "#d96500\r\n\r\n",
        "source": "Região Autónoma dos Açores ",
        "target": "Norte",
        "id2": "11",
        "value": "33",
        "total": "7079",
        "percentagem": "0.47"
    },
    {
        "id": "20",
        "color": "#bdb66c\r\n",
        "source": "Região Autónoma dos Açores ",
        "target": "Algarve",
        "id2": "15",
        "value": "8",
        "total": "7079",
        "percentagem": "0.11"
    },
    {
        "id": "20",
        "color": "#bdaf57\r\n",
        "source": "Região Autónoma dos Açores ",
        "target": "Centro",
        "id2": "16",
        "value": "42",
        "total": "7079",
        "percentagem": "0.59"
    },
    {
        "id": "20",
        "color": "#fffbc4\r\n",
        "source": "Região Autónoma dos Açores ",
        "target": "Lisboa",
        "id2": "17",
        "value": "132",
        "total": "7079",
        "percentagem": "1.86"
    },
    {
        "id": "20",
        "color": "#f5b367",
        "source": "Região Autónoma dos Açores ",
        "target": "Alentejo",
        "id2": "18",
        "value": "11",
        "total": "7079",
        "percentagem": "0.16"
    },
    {
        "id": "20",
        "color": "#f5b367\r\n",
        "source": "Região Autónoma dos Açores ",
        "target": "Região Autónoma dos Açores",
        "id2": "20",
        "value": "6838",
        "total": "7079",
        "percentagem": "96.60"
    },
    {
        "id": "20",
        "color": "#decf00\r\n",
        "source": "Região Autónoma dos Açores ",
        "target": "Região Autónoma da Madeira",
        "id2": "30",
        "value": "15",
        "total": "7079",
        "percentagem": "0.21"
    },
    {
        "id": "30",
        "color": "#d96500\r\n\r\n",
        "source": "Região Autónoma da Madeira ",
        "target": "Norte",
        "id2": "11",
        "value": "71",
        "total": "7537",
        "percentagem": "0.94"
    },
    {
        "id": "30",
        "color": "#bdb66c\r\n",
        "source": "Região Autónoma da Madeira ",
        "target": "Algarve",
        "id2": "15",
        "value": "6",
        "total": "7537",
        "percentagem": "0.08"
    },
    {
        "id": "30",
        "color": "#bdaf57\r\n",
        "source": "Região Autónoma da Madeira ",
        "target": "Centro",
        "id2": "16",
        "value": "53",
        "total": "7537",
        "percentagem": "0.70"
    },
    {
        "id": "30",
        "color": "#fffbc4\r\n",
        "source": "Região Autónoma da Madeira ",
        "target": "Lisboa",
        "id2": "17",
        "value": "92",
        "total": "7537",
        "percentagem": "1.22"
    },
    {
        "id": "30",
        "color": "#f5b367",
        "source": "Região Autónoma da Madeira ",
        "target": "Alentejo",
        "id2": "18",
        "value": "17",
        "total": "7537",
        "percentagem": "0.23"
    },
    {
        "id": "30",
        "color": "#f5b367\r\n",
        "source": "Região Autónoma da Madeira ",
        "target": "Região Autónoma dos Açores",
        "id2": "20",
        "value": "7",
        "total": "7537",
        "percentagem": "0.09"
    },
    {
        "id": "30",
        "color": "#decf00\r\n",
        "source": "Região Autónoma da Madeira ",
        "target": "Região Autónoma da Madeira",
        "id2": "30",
        "value": "7291",
        "total": "7537",
        "percentagem": "96.74"
    }
] ,"nodes": [
    {
        "name": "Norte ",
        "color": "#d96500\r\n\r\n",
        "xpos": "0"
    },
    {
        "name": "Norte",
        "color": "#d96500\r\n\r\n",
        "xpos": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "Algarve ",
        "color": "#bdb66c\r\n",
        "xpos": "0"
    },
    {
        "name": "Algarve",
        "color": "#bdb66c\r\n",
        "xpos": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "Centro ",
        "color": "#bdaf57\r\n",
        "xpos": "0"
    },
    {
        "name": "Centro",
        "color": "#bdaf57\r\n",
        "xpos": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "Lisboa ",
        "color": "#fffbc4\r\n",
        "xpos": "0"
    },
    {
        "name": "Lisboa",
        "color": "#fffbc4\r\n",
        "xpos": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "Alentejo ",
        "color": "#f5b367",
        "xpos": "0"
    },
    {
        "name": "Alentejo",
        "color": "#f5b367",
        "xpos": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "Região Autónoma dos Açores ",
        "color": "#f5b367\r\n",
        "xpos": "0"
    },
    {
        "name": "Região Autónoma dos Açores",
        "color": "#f5b367\r\n",
        "xpos": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "Região Autónoma da Madeira ",
        "color": "#decf00\r\n",
        "xpos": "0"
    },
    {
        "name": "Região Autónoma da Madeira",
        "color": "#decf00\r\n",
        "xpos": "1"
    }
]}
```

outros dados 
[outros dados do ficheiro](http://pastebin.com/xSeCLc3F)

Comment: Você quer saber se a biblioteca recebe um json como parâmetro?

Comment: com este exemplo em vez da matrix.json tenho de de gerar a partir de origem , destino ,quantiadade http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/150496/gr%C3%A1fico-chord-usado-o-d3-js

Comment: Colega, bem vindo ao SOPT. Este site não é um fórum. Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour] e, principalmente, leia [ask]. Você mesmo postou o link de outra pergunta sua que parece exatamente a mesma coisa.

Comment: @LuizVieira concordo que a pergunta referenciada no link deve ser até mesmo fechada, agora essa aqui até pode ser retrata, concorda. obs: vou copiar sua frase, ficou boa.

Comment: @user2964140 desconheço um unico diagrama que não possa ser feito usando o `D3.js`. você pode consultar a documentação para este tipo de grafico: [d3-chord](https://github.com/d3/d3-chord/blob/master/README.md#chord) e os seguintes exemplos: [Uber Rides by Neighborhood](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/uberdata/), [The Euro Debt Crisis](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1308257) e [Chord Diagram](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062006)

Comment: seu comentário não conseguiu ajudar sua pergunta. Pare, pense, reflita onde você quer chegar, entenda a sua dúvida, isso é essencial. Tente fazer isso, caso contrário, será complicado você se expressar. Essa é uma dica para sua vida. Expresse-se com objetividade.

Comment: a minha duvida esta mesmo na matriz

Comment: @durtto Oi. Não sei se entendi o que você quis dizer. Vc sugeriu deixar esta aberta e fechar a outra como duplicata desta? Se sim, tanto faz. O AP pode (deve, na verdade) [edit] esta (qualquer uma, de fato) para melhorá-la.

Comment: User[...], que matriz? E daí, qual é a dúvida sobre a matriz? Enfim, tanto nessa como na outra pergunta a sua dúvida é "É possível criar um gráfico"? E a resposta é: sim. Edite a pergunta para deixar diretamente mais claro qual exatamente é a sua dificuldade.

Comment: P.S.: E, sério, leia [ask]. Vai te ajudar. :)

Answer (score 1):

Peguei como exemplo o [`Uber Rides by Neighborhood`](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/uberdata/) que está disponivel no proprio site do `d3.js`.

a primeira etapa, seria converter o seu source para o formato usado no exemplo.:

```
var data = {"links": [
  {
    "id": "11",
    "color": "#d96500\r\n\r\n",
    "source": "Norte ",
    "target": "Norte",
    "id2": "11",
    "value": "110042",
    "total": "112827",
    "percentagem": "97.53"
  },
  {
    "id": "11",
    "color": "#bdb66c\r\n",
    "source": "Norte ",
    "target": "Algarve",
    "id2": "15",
    "value": "148",
    "total": "112827",
    "percentagem": "0.13"
  },
  {
    "id": "11",
    "color": "#bdaf57\r\n",
    "source": "Norte ",
    "target": "Centro",
    "id2": "16",
    "value": "1533",
    "total": "112827",
    "percentagem": "1.36"
  },
  {
    "id": "11",
    "color": "#fffbc4\r\n",
    "source": "Norte ",
    "target": "Lisboa",
    "id2": "17",
    "value": "810",
    "total": "112827",
    "percentagem": "0.72"
  },
  {
    "id": "11",
    "color": "#f5b367",
    "source": "Norte ",
    "target": "Alentejo",
    "id2": "18",
    "value": "180",
    "total": "112827",
    "percentagem": "0.16"
  },
  {
    "id": "11",
    "color": "#f5b367\r\n",
    "source": "Norte ",
    "target": "Região Autónoma dos Açores",
    "id2": "20",
    "value": "66",
    "total": "112827",
    "percentagem": "0.06"
  },
  {
    "id": "11",
    "color": "#decf00\r\n",
    "source": "Norte ",
    "target": "Região Autónoma da Madeira",
    "id2": "30",
    "value": "48",
    "total": "112827",
    "percentagem": "0.04"
  },
  {
    "id": "15",
    "color": "#d96500\r\n\r\n",
    "source": "Algarve ",
    "target": "Norte",
    "id2": "11",
    "value": "37",
    "total": "11633",
    "percentagem": "0.32"
  },
  {
    "id": "15",
    "color": "#bdb66c\r\n",
    "source": "Algarve ",
    "target": "Algarve",
    "id2": "15",
    "value": "11202",
    "total": "11633",
    "percentagem": "96.30"
  },
  {
    "id": "15",
    "color": "#bdaf57\r\n",
    "source": "Algarve ",
    "target": "Centro",
    "id2": "16",
    "value": "53",
    "total": "11633",
    "percentagem": "0.46"
  },
  {
    "id": "15",
    "color": "#fffbc4\r\n",
    "source": "Algarve ",
    "target": "Lisboa",
    "id2": "17",
    "value": "240",
    "total": "11633",
    "percentagem": "2.06"
  },
  {
    "id": "15",
    "color": "#f5b367",
    "source": "Algarve ",
    "target": "Alentejo",
    "id2": "18",
    "value": "95",
    "total": "11633",
    "percentagem": "0.82"
  },
  {
    "id": "15",
    "color": "#f5b367\r\n",
    "source": "Algarve ",
    "target": "Região Autónoma dos Açores",
    "id2": "20",
    "value": "4",
    "total": "11633",
    "percentagem": "0.03"
  },
  {
    "id": "15",
    "color": "#decf00\r\n",
    "source": "Algarve ",
    "target": "Região Autónoma da Madeira",
    "id2": "30",
    "value": "2",
    "total": "11633",
    "percentagem": "0.02"
  },
  {
    "id": "16",
    "color": "#d96500\r\n\r\n",
    "source": "Centro ",
    "target": "Norte",
    "id2": "11",
    "value": "1211",
    "total": "68002",
    "percentagem": "1.78"
  },
  {
    "id": "16",
    "color": "#bdb66c\r\n",
    "source": "Centro ",
    "target": "Algarve",
    "id2": "15",
    "value": "143",
    "total": "68002",
    "percentagem": "0.21"
  },
  {
    "id": "16",
    "color": "#bdaf57\r\n",
    "source": "Centro ",
    "target": "Centro",
    "id2": "16",
    "value": "63709",
    "total": "68002",
    "percentagem": "93.69"
  },
  {
    "id": "16",
    "color": "#fffbc4\r\n",
    "source": "Centro ",
    "target": "Lisboa",
    "id2": "17",
    "value": "2249",
    "total": "68002",
    "percentagem": "3.31"
  },
  {
    "id": "16",
    "color": "#f5b367",
    "source": "Centro ",
    "target": "Alentejo",
    "id2": "18",
    "value": "617",
    "total": "68002",
    "percentagem": "0.91"
  },
  {
    "id": "16",
    "color": "#f5b367\r\n",
    "source": "Centro ",
    "target": "Região Autónoma dos Açores",
    "id2": "20",
    "value": "39",
    "total": "68002",
    "percentagem": "0.06"
  },
  {
    "id": "16",
    "color": "#decf00\r\n",
    "source": "Centro ",
    "target": "Região Autónoma da Madeira",
    "id2": "30",
    "value": "34",
    "total": "68002",
    "percentagem": "0.05"
  },
  {
    "id": "17",
    "color": "#d96500\r\n\r\n",
    "source": "Lisboa ",
    "target": "Norte",
    "id2": "11",
    "value": "279",
    "total": "83584",
    "percentagem": "0.33"
  },
  {
    "id": "17",
    "color": "#bdb66c\r\n",
    "source": "Lisboa ",
    "target": "Algarve",
    "id2": "15",
    "value": "272",
    "total": "83584",
    "percentagem": "0.33"
  },
  {
    "id": "17",
    "color": "#bdaf57\r\n",
    "source": "Lisboa ",
    "target": "Centro",
    "id2": "16",
    "value": "960",
    "total": "83584",
    "percentagem": "1.15"
  },
  {
    "id": "17",
    "color": "#fffbc4\r\n",
    "source": "Lisboa ",
    "target": "Lisboa",
    "id2": "17",
    "value": "81247",
    "total": "83584",
    "percentagem": "97.20"
  },
  {
    "id": "17",
    "color": "#f5b367",
    "source": "Lisboa ",
    "target": "Alentejo",
    "id2": "18",
    "value": "726",
    "total": "83584",
    "percentagem": "0.87"
  },
  {
    "id": "17",
    "color": "#f5b367\r\n",
    "source": "Lisboa ",
    "target": "Região Autónoma dos Açores",
    "id2": "20",
    "value": "46",
    "total": "83584",
    "percentagem": "0.06"
  },
  {
    "id": "17",
    "color": "#decf00\r\n",
    "source": "Lisboa ",
    "target": "Região Autónoma da Madeira",
    "id2": "30",
    "value": "54",
    "total": "83584",
    "percentagem": "0.06"
  },
  {
    "id": "18",
    "color": "#d96500\r\n\r\n",
    "source": "Alentejo ",
    "target": "Norte",
    "id2": "11",
    "value": "46",
    "total": "21572",
    "percentagem": "0.21"
  },
  {
    "id": "18",
    "color": "#bdb66c\r\n",
    "source": "Alentejo ",
    "target": "Algarve",
    "id2": "15",
    "value": "195",
    "total": "21572",
    "percentagem": "0.90"
  },
  {
    "id": "18",
    "color": "#bdaf57\r\n",
    "source": "Alentejo ",
    "target": "Centro",
    "id2": "16",
    "value": "508",
    "total": "21572",
    "percentagem": "2.35"
  },
  {
    "id": "18",
    "color": "#fffbc4\r\n",
    "source": "Alentejo ",
    "target": "Lisboa",
    "id2": "17",
    "value": "1265",
    "total": "21572",
    "percentagem": "5.86"
  },
  {
    "id": "18",
    "color": "#f5b367",
    "source": "Alentejo ",
    "target": "Alentejo",
    "id2": "18",
    "value": "19542",
    "total": "21572",
    "percentagem": "90.59"
  },
  {
    "id": "18",
    "color": "#f5b367\r\n",
    "source": "Alentejo ",
    "target": "Região Autónoma dos Açores",
    "id2": "20",
    "value": "8",
    "total": "21572",
    "percentagem": "0.04"
  },
  {
    "id": "18",
    "color": "#decf00\r\n",
    "source": "Alentejo ",
    "target": "Região Autónoma da Madeira",
    "id2": "30",
    "value": "8",
    "total": "21572",
    "percentagem": "0.04"
  },
  {
    "id": "20",
    "color": "#d96500\r\n\r\n",
    "source": "Região Autónoma dos Açores ",
    "target": "Norte",
    "id2": "11",
    "value": "33",
    "total": "7079",
    "percentagem": "0.47"
  },
  {
    "id": "20",
    "color": "#bdb66c\r\n",
    "source": "Região Autónoma dos Açores ",
    "target": "Algarve",
    "id2": "15",
    "value": "8",
    "total": "7079",
    "percentagem": "0.11"
  },
  {
    "id": "20",
    "color": "#bdaf57\r\n",
    "source": "Região Autónoma dos Açores ",
    "target": "Centro",
    "id2": "16",
    "value": "42",
    "total": "7079",
    "percentagem": "0.59"
  },
  {
    "id": "20",
    "color": "#fffbc4\r\n",
    "source": "Região Autónoma dos Açores ",
    "target": "Lisboa",
    "id2": "17",
    "value": "132",
    "total": "7079",
    "percentagem": "1.86"
  },
  {
    "id": "20",
    "color": "#f5b367",
    "source": "Região Autónoma dos Açores ",
    "target": "Alentejo",
    "id2": "18",
    "value": "11",
    "total": "7079",
    "percentagem": "0.16"
  },
  {
    "id": "20",
    "color": "#f5b367\r\n",
    "source": "Região Autónoma dos Açores ",
    "target": "Região Autónoma dos Açores",
    "id2": "20",
    "value": "6838",
    "total": "7079",
    "percentagem": "96.60"
  },
  {
    "id": "20",
    "color": "#decf00\r\n",
    "source": "Região Autónoma dos Açores ",
    "target": "Região Autónoma da Madeira",
    "id2": "30",
    "value": "15",
    "total": "7079",
    "percentagem": "0.21"
  },
  {
    "id": "30",
    "color": "#d96500\r\n\r\n",
    "source": "Região Autónoma da Madeira ",
    "target": "Norte",
    "id2": "11",
    "value": "71",
    "total": "7537",
    "percentagem": "0.94"
  },
  {
    "id": "30",
    "color": "#bdb66c\r\n",
    "source": "Região Autónoma da Madeira ",
    "target": "Algarve",
    "id2": "15",
    "value": "6",
    "total": "7537",
    "percentagem": "0.08"
  },
  {
    "id": "30",
    "color": "#bdaf57\r\n",
    "source": "Região Autónoma da Madeira ",
    "target": "Centro",
    "id2": "16",
    "value": "53",
    "total": "7537",
    "percentagem": "0.70"
  },
  {
    "id": "30",
    "color": "#fffbc4\r\n",
    "source": "Região Autónoma da Madeira ",
    "target": "Lisboa",
    "id2": "17",
    "value": "92",
    "total": "7537",
    "percentagem": "1.22"
  },
  {
    "id": "30",
    "color": "#f5b367",
    "source": "Região Autónoma da Madeira ",
    "target": "Alentejo",
    "id2": "18",
    "value": "17",
    "total": "7537",
    "percentagem": "0.23"
  },
  {
    "id": "30",
    "color": "#f5b367\r\n",
    "source": "Região Autónoma da Madeira ",
    "target": "Região Autónoma dos Açores",
    "id2": "20",
    "value": "7",
    "total": "7537",
    "percentagem": "0.09"
  },
  {
    "id": "30",
    "color": "#decf00\r\n",
    "source": "Região Autónoma da Madeira ",
    "target": "Região Autónoma da Madeira",
    "id2": "30",
    "value": "7291",
    "total": "7537",
    "percentagem": "96.74"
  }
] ,"nodes": [
  {
    "name": "Norte ",
    "color": "#d96500\r\n\r\n",
    "xpos": "0"
  },
  {
    "name": "Norte",
    "color": "#d96500\r\n\r\n",
    "xpos": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Algarve ",
    "color": "#bdb66c\r\n",
    "xpos": "0"
  },
  {
    "name": "Algarve",
    "color": "#bdb66c\r\n",
    "xpos": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Centro ",
    "color": "#bdaf57\r\n",
    "xpos": "0"
  },
  {
    "name": "Centro",
    "color": "#bdaf57\r\n",
    "xpos": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Lisboa ",
    "color": "#fffbc4\r\n",
    "xpos": "0"
  },
  {
    "name": "Lisboa",
    "color": "#fffbc4\r\n",
    "xpos": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Alentejo ",
    "color": "#f5b367",
    "xpos": "0"
  },
  {
    "name": "Alentejo",
    "color": "#f5b367",
    "xpos": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Região Autónoma dos Açores ",
    "color": "#f5b367\r\n",
    "xpos": "0"
  },
  {
    "name": "Região Autónoma dos Açores",
    "color": "#f5b367\r\n",
    "xpos": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Região Autónoma da Madeira ",
    "color": "#decf00\r\n",
    "xpos": "0"
  },
  {
    "name": "Região Autónoma da Madeira",
    "color": "#decf00\r\n",
    "xpos": "1"
  }
]}

var cities = data.nodes.filter(function (node, indice) {
  return node.xpos == 0;
}).map(function (node, indice) {
  return {
    indice: indice,
    name: node.name.trim(),
    color: node.color.substring(0, 7).toUpperCase()
  }
});

var matrix = [];
data.links.forEach(function (node, indice) {
  var source = cities.filter(function (city, indice) {
    return city.name == node.source.trim();
  })[0].indice;
  var target = cities.filter(function (city, indice) {
    return city.name == node.target.trim();
  })[0].indice;
  if (!matrix[source])
    matrix[source] = [];
  matrix[source][target] = parseInt(node.value);
});
```

o JSON resultante será semelhante ao seguinte.:

```
var cities = [{"indice":0,"name":"Norte","color":"#D96500"},{"indice":1,"name":"Algarve","color":"#BDB66C"},{"indice":2,"name":"Centro","color":"#BDAF57"},{"indice":3,"name":"Lisboa","color":"#FFFBC4"},{"indice":4,"name":"Alentejo","color":"#F5B367"},{"indice":5,"name":"Região Autónoma dos Açores","color":"#F5B367"},{"indice":6,"name":"Região Autónoma da Madeira","color":"#DECF00"}];
var matrix = [[110042,148,1533,810,180,66,48],[37,11202,53,240,95,4,2],[1211,143,63709,2249,617,39,34],[279,272,960,81247,726,46,54],[46,195,508,1265,19542,8,8],[33,8,42,132,11,6838,15],[71,6,53,92,17,7,7291]];
```

como ultimo passo, execute o seguinte script para renderizar o grafico.:

```
var formatPercent = d3.format(".1%");

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.innerRadius(innerRadius)
.outerRadius(outerRadius);

var layout = d3.layout.chord()
.padding(.04)
.sortSubgroups(d3.descending)
.sortChords(d3.ascending);

var path = d3.svg.chord()
.radius(innerRadius);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.append("g")
.attr("id", "circle")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

svg.append("circle")
.attr("r", outerRadius);

// Compute the chord layout.
layout.matrix(matrix);

// Add a group per neighborhood.
var group = svg.selectAll(".group")
.data(layout.groups)
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "group")
.on("mouseover", mouseover);

// Add a mouseover title.
group.append("title").text(function(d, i) {
  return cities[i].name + ": " + formatPercent(d.value) + " of origins";
});

// Add the group arc.
var groupPath = group.append("path")
.attr("id", function(d, i) { return "group" + i; })
.attr("d", arc)
.style("fill", function(d, i) { return cities[i].color; });

// Add a text label.
var groupText = group.append("text")
.attr("x", 6)
.attr("dy", 15);

groupText.append("textPath")
.attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) { return "#group" + i; })
.text(function(d, i) { return cities[i].name; });

// Remove the labels that don't fit. :(
groupText.filter(function(d, i) { return groupPath[0][i].getTotalLength() / 2 - 16 < this.getComputedTextLength(); })
.remove();

// Add the chords.
var chord = svg.selectAll(".chord")
.data(layout.chords)
.enter().append("path")
.attr("class", "chord")
.style("fill", function(d) { return cities[d.source.index].color; })
.attr("d", path);

// Add an elaborate mouseover title for each chord.
chord.append("title").text(function(d) {
  return cities[d.source.index].name
  + " → " + cities[d.target.index].name
  + ": " + formatPercent(d.source.value)
  + "\n" + cities[d.target.index].name
  + " → " + cities[d.source.index].name
  + ": " + formatPercent(d.target.value);
});

function mouseover(d, i) {
  chord.classed("fade", function(p) {
    return p.source.index != i
    && p.target.index != i;
  });
}
```

Como o script ficou um tanto quanto longo, não foi possivel colocar o exemplo completo direto na resposta, mas você pode conferir o seguinte fiddle.: **[`JSFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/TobyMosque/remddfLd/)**

Comment: eu queria em percentagens como esta no exemplo e nao valor absoluto

Comment: @user2964140 o TobyMosque fez um excelente esforço para te ajudar e basicamente resolver o teu problema. Testaste fazer essa ultima adaptação? (pergunto para ter certeza que fazes a tua parte de tentar dar o proximo passo com a ajuda que aqui foi dada...)

Comment: sim consegui.mas agora estou com um problema fazendo o output com o php não esta a funcionar

Comment: $body = $("body");
    $body.addClass("loading")
    var data=  d3.json("../querys/chord.php")
          .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
           .post('ano=' + anoid + '&sexo=' + sexo + '&meiovida=' + meiovida + '&faixaetaria=' + faixaetaria + '&alfabeto=' + alfabeto + '&opcaoresidencia=' + opcaoresidencia + action)
        $body.removeClass("loading");

Comment: vou colocar outros dados aqui http://pastebin.com/xSeCLc3F

Comment: @user2964140 nesse caso deves colocar o novo problema numa pergunta nova. Para que cada pergunta /resposta fiquem mais específivas.